# How to change an element's class when viewport changes in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change an element's class when the viewport changes?

For instance, when Bootstrap renders an element on viewport `lg`, the elements have a class called `css-class`. But when the viewport is `md`, I need it to change that element class to `css-class2`

Answer (score 3):

When you want to give classes to elements based on the viewport you could write a simple check in JavaScript based on Bootstrap's viewport.

```
if(screen.width >= bootstrap-viewport) {
  $(elements).removeClass('otherClasses');
  $(elements).addClass('someExampleClass');
}
```

You can however use media queries in CSS to give elements specific styling per viewport. This is a **cleaner and more maintainable** solution. A small example:

```
.content-area {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

@media(min-width: @screen-desktop) {
    .content-area {
      line-height: 1.6em;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do believe the second code is cleaner as well , you'll need to listen to an event before executing the first code, and the second doesn't rely on javascript , thank you

Comment: Your welcome, also the CSS solution keeps your styling where it belongs. In the CSS and not in the JavaScript files.